# Find conjugate transpose (adjoint) of linear transform

Tags: linear-algebra, transformation, inner-products, orthonormal

A difficult question I've been trying to tackle but I seem to hit a dead end.

Let $V$ be an inner product space over $\mathbb R$. We are required to find $T^{*}$ such that $$\left<T(u),v\right> = \left<u,T^{*}(v)\right>$$ where:

$$T(u) = u-\frac{2\left<v,u\right>}{\left<v,v\right>}v$$ and $v$ is some vector in $V$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's simple to see that *(just calculate it)*
$$\langle T(u),v\rangle=\langle u-2\frac{\langle v,u\rangle}{\langle v,v\rangle}v,v\rangle=\langle u,v\rangle-2\frac{\langle v,u\rangle}{\langle v,v\rangle}\langle v,v\rangle=-\langle u,v\rangle=\langle u,-\mathrm{id}(v)\rangle$$
so $T^*=-\mathrm{id}$.

Comment: I think you're assuming the inner product is *real*, @Sami...

Comment: Yes $V$ is an inner product space over $\mathbb R$ as mentioned by the OP.

Comment: Obviously if what you are saying is true then $T^{*}=-id$ but how is it simple to see? I'd like to see your calculation. I think we can assume the inner product is real since $V$ is over $\mathbb R$

Comment: Yes, indeed. As the title says "conjugate"...+1

Comment: @OriaGruber I edited my answer.

Comment: noticed. much obliged.